# Ceiling Fan wiring - odd voltage measurements

Tags: ceiling-fan, voltage

I replaced a ceiling fan because the fan motor was not working, but the lights were.
I ​would have assumed I would wire the Red (R) wire to the black and blue ceiling fan wires and the White (W) wire to the ceiling fan white wire. Of course also attach the Green (G) ground wires and just cap the Black (B) wire in the ceiling fixture.

However, when I did this nothing works. So, I measured the voltage coming from the wires and have confusing results. Why these odd results?
W/B - 230 volts. This means both wires are hot, right?
W/R - 50 volts with the wall switch one way, 230 volts with the switch the other way.
R/B - 160 volts with the wall switch one way, 5 volts with the wall switch the other way.

I expected W/R would show 120 volts switched on and 0 volts switched off.

Comment: Links and pics to the switch and fan as well as a clear picture of the wiring in both boxes pls.  Where u at boi (Electrical codes differ by region)?  Do you have the manual for the fan and were there originally separate light and fan switches?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? How many switches controlled this setup? Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Quit making assumptions would be the best advice. Read the instructions, if you don’t know or understand your voltages you can fry a fan motor (let the magic smoke out) in about 1 second if the motor is 120v and was connected to 240v like in a multiwire branch circuit used in the US. The fan model would be helpful and your location.

Comment: This in Dallas, TX area.    Do not have the old ceiling fan instructions.  The power to the fan is controlled by two separate switches in the house (one switch in the master bedroom and one in the family room)